# Azure DevOps - Deploy Web application to IIS

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops

**Requirement:** I am trying to deploy a website in IIS and within the same website in IIS, I am trying to add an application running under the same website. Something as shown in the below screenshot:

[image]

I have added a deployment group and a registered a dev server in the group.

[image: Deployment Group]

[image: Server or machine added]

I have already created a **Release Pipeline** and configured the job and task for the IIS deployment.

[image: IIS Config]

[image]

My website in the IIS now gets configured after I build and deploy it via the release pipeline.

[image]

So in order yo achieve my requirement, I need to now add an "Application" in IIS under the same website. So in order to achieve this, I have created a new **Release Pipeline** and tried configuring jobs and task, but i am not able to see/select any deployment group from the "Deployment group job". Please review screenshot below:

[image]

[image]

Can anyone suggest how can I see the deployment group for my new release pipeline?
Also, please do suggest if there are any other possible solutions to achieve my requirement.

Comment: Do you have other environment settings that cause this problem? Do you have this issue if you add a default release pipeline (without any changes)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved there was some security issue that was not allowing me to view/select the deployment group.

It has been resolved.